# Add domain Administrator to existing roaming profiles (WS 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We had an unfortunate encounter with a crypto-locker. I am trying to scan the roaming profiles with several anti viruses, but unfortunately I have no access rights.

Is there a way to add DOMAIN\Administrators to allow them read (and write) access on the folders? Any power-shell scripts?

Is there a way to access these files? I wanted to use a LiveCD but due to the HP Smart Raid Controller I can't get direct access to the files.

Best,

Emite

Comment: can't you log into the server and reclaim ownership of the files and then give the rights you need?  What is your plan....to restore from backup?

Comment: Shouldn't any competent antivirus run its background scanning task in a system context regardless of what the UI's doing anyway?

Comment: `Is there a way to add DOMAIN\Administrators to allow them read (and write) access on the folders? Any power-shell scripts?` - Sure. Powershell, icacls, the GUI... any of these can be used to add NTFS permissions to the folders for any user you choose. If you're asking us how to do it then that's a different question than the one you asked.